# What is alternate of ServiceBus MessagingFactory in .Net Core?

Tags: azure, .net-core, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

While converting my project from .Net framework 4.7 to .Net core 2.1, I'm facing issue with Servicebus `MessagingFactory`. I don't see any `MessagingFactory` class in new nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` for .Net core.

**My .Net framework 4.7 Code**

```
private static readonly string messagingConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnection");

    private static Lazy<MessagingFactory> lazyMessagingFactory = new Lazy<MessagingFactory>(() =>
    {
        return MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(messagingConnectionString);
    });

    public static MessagingFactory MessagingFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyMessagingFactory.Value;
        }
    }

public static MessagingFactory EventHubMessageFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyEventhubMessagingFactory.Value;
        }
    }

public async Task SendMessageToQueueAsync(string queueName, string message)
    {
        QueueClient queueClient = MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)), true);
        await queueClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    }
```

It was a [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients) for high performance application, Also I have many queues under single service bus namespace and I push message based on configuration. I don't want to create `QueueClient` object in every request and don't want to maintain connection string for every queue.

What is alternate of `MessagingFactory` in .Net Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are major changes when you are migrating .NetFramework code into .Netcore, you can see [Guide for migrating to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md)

**Example below**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
        string queueName = "<queue_name>";
        // since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

        // create the sender
        ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // create a message that we can send. UTF-8 encoding is used when providing a string.
            ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage($"Hello world {i}!");

            // send the message
            sender.SendMessageAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        }
    
    sender.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    client.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46830

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/556

> While MessagingFactory is gone, the idea of connection pooling and sharing connections is there. When you create your clients, passing a connection will reuse it. When passing a connection string, will cause clients to establish a new connection.

So you can manually create a [ServiceBusConnection](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/ServiceBusConnection.cs) or reuse one of an existing client. You can pass the connection object in the constructors of the clients you create. Take care not to close a connection accidentally, e.g. by closing the client that created it.

Comment: Thanks for the above link but still now sure how the connection will resue. I'm sending millions of messages every day in the queue based on data, changing the name of queue.

Comment: I can't keep connection alive for every queue